# how do you run a commamd say npm install or rake as part of a node js application?

Tags: node.js, npm, nodes

I have a node app in which i want to run a command or task like npm install or rake or git clone . I tried using child process exec , but is not running the npm install task. Is there a alternative way?

Comment: are these tasks you want to run when the application loads ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to execute a `shell` (or `cmd` if you're on Windows) command you can do it by using `child_process.exec()`

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Here is an example:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child;

child = exec("pwd", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

Just put `npm install` or `git clone` or whatever you want to execute instead of `pwd` when calling the `exec` function.

Comment: can this be done synchronusly and get the stdout and stderr after the function is excecuted.

Comment: Yes, you can use `child_process.execSync()`: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to get `npm install` work inside a node script,

Execute `npm install npm --save` (This will take some time)

Now since npm is inside the node_modules folder, you can import it inside your script.
Sample script below which installs 'foobar' package

```
var npm = require("npm");
npm.load(function (err) {
      npm.commands.install(["foobar"], function (err, data) {
  });
  npm.on("log", function (message) {
    // progress of the npm install
    console.log(message);
  });
});
```

This is just an alternative. Use `child_process` as suggested by Lucian